# Should data be passed in to functions in MVC models?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Let's say I have a HTML contact form with 3 fields. On submit, the form triggers `contact()`in my Contact controller.

In Contact controller:

```
function contact() {

    // Check if form was submitted
    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {

        $response = $this->contact_model->send($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message']);

        if ($response === 1) {
            // Redirect or something
        }
    }

    // Load contact view
}
```

In Contact_model:

```
function send($name, $email, $message) {

    // Validate form data

    // Save or send (whatever)

    // If no errors, return 1
}
```

What I'm wondering here is if I'm doing it right? Since my model should not care about if the data is coming through $_GET or $_POST or something else, I thought I'd better pass it in. This require me to first check if the required post variables are sent (using isset()), and then pass everything in. It gets kinda messy, as opposed to just using $_POST in my model (not having to do any validation or passing in my controller).

Basically, what's the ideal way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should handle the first level of cleansing of any user input. That way, if the data is incorrect or malicious, your controller can hook up the correct error view and render it to the user.

Typically (and I know purists will disagree with me..), but typically when the data reaches the model, the model should assume that the data is sanitized and just worry about its validity in terms of the business logic. So once your controller cleans up and sends data to the model, the data is invalid to the model only if it breaks some business rule or so.

Comment: I suppose sanitized in this context just means that the data exists, i.e. that the required POST variables are set? Checking if valid email, if is a number within a range or valid date etc. should be done by the model, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but also ensuring that there are no malicious content - usually general security checks are conducted by controllers and business level logic checks are conducted by models. Of course this is not a rigid immutable practice, but that is how it is for the most part

Comment: @raidenace you are completely wrong. Controllers are **not responsible for validation** or sanitation of user's input. Validation is a responsibility of [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) within the model layer.

Comment: lol, teresko, everytime I write anything about MVC, you always show up...how do you even know where I answered!!! :) Like I have mentioned before - there are no rigid rules for MVC...I use controllers for generic validation and Models for domain validations. So sue me...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to not care about if the data is coming through `$_GET`, or `$_POST`, `send` can take an array of data, and you will put `$_GET` or `$_POST`. Then you can validate your data in `send`:

**Contact controller:**

```php
<?php
function contact() {
    $response = $this->contact_model->send($_POST);

    if ($response === 1) {
        // Redirect or something
    }

    // Load contact view
}
?>
```

**Contact model:**

```php
<?php
function send($data) {
    // Validate form data

    // Save or send (whatever)

    // If no errors, return 1
}
?>
```